# Error installing Pusher PHP library with PHP 8.2.6 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm encountering an error while trying to install the Pusher PHP library in Laravel, specifically when using PHP version 8.2.6. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:v4.1.1
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update pusher/pusher-php-server
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server v4.1.1 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[v4.1.1].
- pusher/pusher-php-server v4.1.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- pusher/pusher-php-server v4.1.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.2.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.14.0 requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0|^4.0|^5.0|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[v4.1.1].
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets is locked to version 1.14.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I understand that the error is related to the Pusher PHP library's requirement of PHP version 7.1, which my environment doesn't meet (PHP 8.2.6 is installed). However, I would prefer not to downgrade my PHP version.

I have tried specifying a different version of the Pusher PHP library using the command `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server:v4.1.1`, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Is there any solution or workaround to install the Pusher PHP library (specifically version 3.0 or higher) with PHP 8.2.6 in Laravel? Any guidance or alternative libraries that provide similar functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: v4.1.1 is nearly **four years** old. Why not use any more recent version? It's pretty obvious that is is not compatible with PHP 8.2, as this hasn't been released until Dec 2022

Comment: Have you tried any of the 7.* versions? https://packagist.org/packages/pusher/pusher-php-server#7.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this,

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

it will install the latest version  that supports php 8.